# Can I publish Google spreadsheet add-on without verification?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I tried to publish an add-on and Google reviewed it. They sent me this:

> Please check that your add-on doesn’t comply with the Google OAuth verification, please follow the steps in our dev guide related to this, fill this form, and wait for the OAuth team response before submitting it again.

Can I somehow publish an add-on without filling OAuth Developer Verification Form? I saw lots of add-ons that are unverified and can be used.

Comment: You can publish an add-on as unlisted, which doesn't go through the authorization process.  There are 3 choices; 3 radio buttons at the bottom of the window.  You need to scroll down to click the Publish button, so look to the left side and you'll see the other options.

Comment: @SandyGood but it wont be seen in the add-on store if i publish as unlisted, right?

Comment: That is correct.  The only way for someone to discover your unlisted add-on is if you somehow promote it yourself.  So, if you want it published on the Chrome Web Store, you must go through the approval process.  And that includes having a privacy policy posted in a site that you own.  And you must verify ownership of the site.  Some types of permissions are more "sensitive" than others, for example access to the users email account is considered to be a "sensitive" permission.

Comment: @SandyGood thanks for the help!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54222704/1595451

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot of the specifics, but publishing as add-on but keeping it to a private domain was an easier process. Mind you, it was still an annoying process.

If you're just looking to use it for yourself, you can create a button in your sheet that links to the function (excel-style).