# Set Google project to private

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, verification

I got an email today about Google requiring Google apps with sensitive authorization scopes needing to be submitted for verification if they're going to continue to work after Feb 15. Thing is, I have no intention of my projects being publically available. They're just small projects for me to practice with and occasionally actually perform a service, but only for me.

It does say that "Verification is required if your app is marked as Public and. . .", but I can't find anywhere to change my project from Public to Private. Where do I find this setting at?

Comment: I would guess that deploying with execute the app as user accessing the app  and accessible to anyone would be considered public.

Comment: Add more details about your project. Is it a stand-alone, bounded ? Is it a web application?

Comment: I have 3 projects in total, I access all of which through the script.google.com URL which takes me to the GSuite Developer Hub. I'm not familiar with those terms specifically, but two of them are actually attached to spreadsheets, so I think those might be considered bounded. The last one is, I think a web app? It goes through my Gmail looking for a specific email with an attachment and saves that attachment in the appropriate place in my Google Drive.

edit: fixed URL from scripts.google.com to script.google.com